# No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set my-mongo-set maps to this node

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using Docker to setup a MongoDB Cluster.

I've a bash script which starts three containers which share a network bridge so they can talk to each other. I can connect to all the MongoDB databases in the network.

The NodeJS script adds the members of the cluster to the network.

```
docker rm -v -f mongo0
docker rm -v -f mongo1
docker rm -v -f mongo2

docker network create my-mongo-cluster

docker run -d \
-p 30002:27017 \
--name mongo0 \
--net my-mongo-cluster \
mongo mongod --replSet my-mongo-set

docker run -d \
-p 30003:27017 \
--name mongo1 \
--net my-mongo-cluster \
mongo mongod --replSet my-mongo-set

docker run -d \
-p 30004:27017 \
--name mongo2 \
--net my-mongo-cluster \
mongo mongod --replSet my-mongo-set

node setupDatabase.js
```

NodeJS script:

```
async function configure() {
    let database = await connect();

    let adminDb = database.admin();

    await addMembers(adminDb);

    await returnStatus(adminDb);
}

async function connect() {
    return await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:30002/test");
}

async function addMembers(admin) {
    var config = {
        "_id" : "my-mongo-set",
        "members" : [
            {
                "_id" : 0,
                "host" : "mongo0:30002"
            },
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "host" : "mongo1:30003"
            },
            {
                "_id" : 2,
                "host" : "mongo2:30004"
            }
        ]};

    return admin.command({replSetInitiate : config});
}

async function returnStatus(admin) {
    return admin.command({replSetGetStatus : 1});
}
```

Whenever I invoke `addMembers` I get the following error:

> No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set my-mongo-set maps to this node

From my understanding this means that MongoDB cannot connect to the given member. But they all have their own name and share a network bridge. So they should be able to connect to each other.

Any ideas what is causing this issue?

Comment: This is container to container config so use the internal port for each host, 27017

Comment: @Matt I'm a moron, thanks! If you create an answer I can accept your answer as the solution.

Comment: No worries, it's easy to do when your dealing with ports within ports. Answer added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The replication set configuration is container to container so requires the internal container address and port `container-name:27017`

```
var config = {
    "_id" : "my-mongo-set",
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "mongo0:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "mongo1:27017"
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "mongo2:27017"
        }
    ]};
```

It's possible to connect via the Docker mapped ports but then you would need to use a hostname/address that the Docker host can respond to. It would also include unnecessary network hops to get out and back into the containers.

Comment: this help me, I was using a custom port and don't know that I have to add that custom port on the host field.