# "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node " : Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-query, ubuntu-16.04, replicaset

I have installed docker in 3 Ubuntu 16.04 VMs, for each of those VMs docker's containers I run mongodb image using the commande :

> **docker run -d -p 27017:27017  -v data:/data/db mongo --replSet "rs0"**

After that I changed the file 
**/etc/hosts**  of each Vms with adding their Ip(vms) addresses in each file of the 3 Vms

> cat /etc/hosts 
>   127.0.0.1       localhost
>   127.0.1.1       mongodb0
>
> **aa.bb.cc.ee   mongodb0**
>
> **aa.bb.cc.ff   mongodb1**
>
> **aa.bb.cc.gg   mongodb2**

when I use the commande *rs.initiate ()* to deploy replicaset

```
 rs.initiate ( {    
    _id : "rs0",    members: [
       { _id: 0, host: "mongodb0:27017" },
       { _id: 1, host: "mongodb1:27017" },
       { _id: 2, host: "mongodb2:27017" }   
 ] })
```

I have this error :

```
  "operationTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node",
        "code" : 93,
        "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
```

**how can I fix this issue, please?**

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47571358/8543203

Comment: Does this answer your question? [errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node", Why I am getting this message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211285/errmsg-no-host-described-in-new-configuration-1-for-replica-set-rs0-maps-to)