# Kubernetes MongoDB replicaset creation failed

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-replica-set, kubernetes-statefulset

What i intended to do:

1. Setup Kubernetes in Digital Ocean
2. Configure MongoDB replicaset in kubernetes

**EDIT**: Steps that i used to setup Kubernetes

Steps to setup master node:

Docker Setup using : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
$ kubeadm init —pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 —apiserver-advertise-address=<MASTER_IP>
$ kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Kubernetes Version: v1.18.3
Docker Version: 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0

Setting Up Nodes:

Docker Setup using : https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
$ kubeadm join <PUBLIC_IP>:6443 --token <token> \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash <hash>
```

I have completed step1 successfully but unable to configure repliaca set. The rs.initiate() command fails with "**No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node**" error.

```
$kubectl get all
NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mongo-0                                  1/1     Running   0          16m
pod/mongo-1                                  1/1     Running   0          16m
pod/mongo-2                                  1/1     Running   0          16m
pod/nfs-client-provisioner-5d7cbcd58-qs8r6   1/1     Running   0          43h

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP     2d21h
service/mongo        ClusterIP   None         <none>        27017/TCP   16m

NAME                                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nfs-client-provisioner   1/1     1            1           43h

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nfs-client-provisioner-5d7cbcd58   1         1         1       43h

NAME                     READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/mongo   3/3     16m
```

Below command fails:

```
$kubectl exec -it mongo-0 -- mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.2.7
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("64863831-2775-488f-a80d-aabdeb84bad9") }
MongoDB server version: 4.2.7
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
Server has startup warnings: 
2020-05-31T09:46:16.537+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2020-05-31T09:46:16.537+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2020-05-31T09:46:16.537+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2020-05-31T09:46:16.537+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2020-05-31T09:46:16.538+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
---
Enable MongoDB's free cloud-based monitoring service, which will then receive and display
metrics about your deployment (disk utilization, CPU, operation statistics, etc).

The monitoring data will be available on a MongoDB website with a unique URL accessible to you
and anyone you share the URL with. MongoDB may use this information to make product
improvements and to suggest MongoDB products and deployment options to you.

To enable free monitoring, run the following command: db.enableFreeMonitoring()
To permanently disable this reminder, run the following command: db.disableFreeMonitoring()
---

> rs.initiate({_id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [
...   { _id: 0, host : "mongo-0.mongo:27017" },
...   { _id: 1, host : "mongo-1.mongo:27017" },
...   { _id: 2, host : "mongo-2.mongo:27017" }
... ]});
{
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node",
    "code" : 93,
    "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }
}
```

My yamls files:

1.Headless service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mongo
    port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mongo
```

2. mongodb replicate set

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app:  mongo
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        command:
        - mongod
        - "--replSet"
        - rs0
        - "--bind_ip_all"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongo-volume
          mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
```

The issue may be due to DNS. I did the below to fix it with no success:

1. Ensured 27017 is open in Master and worker nodes

```
$ufw allow 27017
```

2. In .yaml tried to set "bind_ip" in .yaml file to 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0

Nothing worked.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to work with this helm package ?https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mongodb-replicaset

Comment: @AmitBaranes, no i have not. Have helm insalled. Do you think helm will help in resolving this issue?

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.. Let me know if you want me to share more info

Comment: @AmitBaranes, Pls share. I havenot used helm to setup MongoDB Replicaset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571358/no-host-described-in-new-configuration-1-for-replica-set-my-mongo-set-maps-to-th

Comment: @D.SM, I am already using port 27017. That link didn't help me. Hope i am missing any info from that link.

Comment: What do you have inside hosts file `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: @PjoterS `127.0.1.1 <hostname> <hostname>  
127.0.0.1 localhost  
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts  
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  
fe00::0 ip6-localnet  
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix  
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters  
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts`

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you have issue with DNS configuration (`No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set rs0 maps to this node`).

Not sure what could cause it as you didn't provide your environment specification, but you can troubleshoot it based on [this Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

Ive run your YAMLS on my `GKE` cluster (unfortunately I don't have access to `Digital Ocean cloud`) and it works without any issues (with `"--bind_ip_all"`).

```
> rs.initiate({_id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [
... ...   { _id: 0, host : "mongo-0.mongo:27017" },
... ...   { _id: 1, host : "mongo-1.mongo:27017" },
... ...   { _id: 2, host : "mongo-2.mongo:27017" }
... ... ]});
{
        "ok" : 1,
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591791921, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591791921, 1)
```

In each of my pods, in `/etc/hosts` besides default entries I have:

```
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP          NODE                                     
mongo-0   1/1     Running   0          122m   10.52.1.6   gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6f885e04-9mdt
mongo-1   1/1     Running   0          121m   10.52.0.3   gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6f885e04-klkb
mongo-2   1/1     Running   0          120m   10.52.1.7   gke-cluster-1-default-pool-6f885e04-9mdt

mongo-0 pod
10.52.1.6       mongo-0.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local mongo-0

mongo-1 pod
10.52.0.3       mongo-1.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local mongo-1

mongo-2 pod
10.52.1.7       mongo-2.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local mongo-2
```

As per Kubernetes docs, [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/), especially part regarding [pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods), inside your hostsfile you should have entry like:

```
hostname.default-subdomain.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example
```

As fast check, you can add this DNS entry manually to your `/etc/host` file in pods and verify.

Another workaround is [Host Aliases](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/).

Let me know it this help. 
If not please provide content of `/etc/hosts`and `/etc/resolv.conf` files from your pods and Kubernetes version.

Also Verify if there are any issues with pods `kubectl get pods -A`.

Comment: Still no luck. Here is my /etc/hosts file. `$kubectl get pods -o wide`. I got the IPs from this command and updated my hosts file in all three nodes.  Here is my content of /etc/hosts.   `192.168.106.29 mongo-0.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local mongo-0
192.168.240.126 mongo-1.mongo.default.svc.cluster.local mongo-1
192.168.106.30 mongo-2.mongo-default.svc.cluster.local mongo-2`

Comment: and /etc/resolv.conf is `nameserver 127.0.0.53 options edns0`.  Kubelet is failing with `failed to run Kubelet: misconfiguration: kubelet cgroup driver: "cgroupfs" is different from docker cgroup driver: "systemd"` error. Is this related to this issue.

Comment: Could you add information to main question how did you create Cluster and what is your Kubernetes and Docker version?

Comment: This issue (almost, in your case kubelet have `cgroupfs` driver and docker have `systemd` driver) was mentioned in [Kubernetes troubleshooting guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/troubleshooting-kubeadm/#kubeadm-blocks-waiting-for-control-plane-during-installation) Easiest way is to change cgroup driver for docker to `cgroupfs`. In Docker installation, step 5 (# Set up the Docker daemon) instead of "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"], use "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"],